# Find all bakeries in LA county with google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, geo

I want to query google maps to give me for example all bakeries in a specific area (e.g. LA County) in terms of longitude and latitude.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is the python library I scraped with, brilliant and well maintained. "Beautiful Soup: We called him Tortoise because he taught us."

Comment: Google maps APIs are rate limited and subject to a quota.  They aren't the right tool to get "all" of anything in any large region (that would most likely be against the terms of us, expensive or both).

Answer (score 2):

In order to collect data through Python you would use something called an API. In this case it would be the Google Maps API.

You first have to request an api key and could than use a python library like: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python to get the data that you need.

The Places API seems like a good way to go forward with if you want to search for specific companies or type of companies.

I hope you are able to find your way using this information and if you have any further questions you can always report back with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not an expert in this subject, you can use a combination of web scraping and pyautogui (python mouse/keyboard) to achieve this. To learn how to use pyautogui, you can go on this link: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/
For a tutorial on web scraping, you can go here:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/